# Access files from different git repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to separate out some files to a another git repository so that different projects can use it. These files contains some common functions that can be used by different projects in gitlab.
How can I access the newly created 'common' repository in my existing project?

Sample code:

`file generate.py contents: *import common_xyz`

`def using_common_xyz: do something...*`

I have now moved the file containing `common_xyz` to a different repository. I read that we can use "Include" keyword in `.gitlab-ci.yml` to access files in other repository. Or should I treat them as library? Can anyone suggest what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git submodules would be the way to go.

From [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of
> another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into
> your project and keep your commits separate.

Here's a [cool guide](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-add-submodules-to-GitHub-repos) (theserverside.com) to get started using both GitHub and GitLab.

Here's [another](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), on git-scm.com